# get variables by **kwargs but throws error about positional arguments

Tags: python

Try to pass the dictionary into the function to print them out, but it throws error: most_courses() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

```
def most_courses(**diction):
    for key, value in diction.items():
        print("{} {}".format(key,value))

most_courses({'Andrew Chalkley': ['jQuery Basics', 'Node.js Basics'],'Kenneth Love': ['Python Basics', 'Python Collections']})
```

I have used **kwargs but why cant python unpack the dictionary?

Comment: you don't need the `**` - you are passing a dict as a parameter.. you need the `**` if you would run the method like `most_courses(k1=v1,k2=v2,...)`

Answer (score 2):

arguments denoted with a ** in the definition of a function need to be passed with a keyword:

#### example:

```
def test(**diction):
    print(diction)
```

Argument passed without keyword:

```
test(8)
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-9-5092d794a50d> in <module>
>       2     print(diction)
>       3 
> ----> 4 test(8)
>       5 test(test_arg=9)
>
> TypeError: test() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
> ```

With arbitrary keyword:

```
test(test_arg=8)
```

output:

```
{'test_arg': 8}
```

### edit:

helpful links:

[Use of *args and **kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/use-of-args-and-kwargs)

[What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

When you pass your dict as a param, you can either do it as you wrote:

```
most_courses({'Andrew Chalkley':  ...
```

in this case `most_cources` should accept a "positional" param. That's why it raises: `most_courses() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`.

You gave it 1 positional param, while `most_cources` (which looks like: `most_courses(**d)`) isn't expecting any..

You should either do:

```
most_courses(**{'Andrew Chalkley': ['jQuery Basics', 'Node.js Basics'],'Kenneth Love': ['Python Basics', 'Python Collections']})
```

OR change the signiture of your method:

```
def most_courses(diction):
    for key, value in diction.items():
        print("{} {}".format(key,value))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use `**` here. You want to pass a dict and have it processed as a dict. Just use a standard argument.

```
def most_courses(diction):
```